# Linq-to-Sql Delete Command not Working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Below is a simple Linq-to-SQL query to delete an address record associated with a given user ID.  It looks correct to me and matches other examples I've followed on the web.  However, when I execute it the record is not deleted.  And there is no error message returned.  What did I do wrong?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int UserID = 250;

        SBMData2.SBMDataContext db = new SBMData2.SBMDataContext();

        var addresses = from a in db.Addresses
                        where a.UserID == UserID
                        select a;

        foreach (var address in addresses)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Addresses.DeleteOnSubmit(address);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Label1.Text = ex.StackTrace.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't submitted any changes in your example. You've only queued the changes to be saved upon submit.

To actually write the changes to the database, you have to call `db.SubmitChanges();`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a

```
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Since your are not submitting the changes the deletes will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd done something like this (untested though)

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userID = 250;
    SBMData2.SBMDataContext db = new SBMData2.SBMDataContext();

    var addresses = db.Addresses.Where(x => x.UserID == userId);

    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Addresses.DeleteOnSubmit(address);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text += ex.StackTrace.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```